# restricting access to a web service based on SSL Client certificates (authorization)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, ssl, certificate

I have a website where I've required client Certificate.

I have configured my IIS website with the following :

```
 <location path="MySecureService">
  <system.webServer>
 <security>
  <access sslFlags="SSl, SslRequireCert"/>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"></windowsAuthentication>
    <digestAuthentication enabled="false"/>
    <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true" >
      <oneToOneMappings>
        <add enabled="true" userName="myUsername" password="myPassword"
             certificate=[certificate-blob-here]
             />
      </oneToOneMappings>
    </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
  </authentication>
</security>
```

I can access this website with "ANY" client certificate that has a root CA recognized by my server. How do I restrict access to only some certificates ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want may be to map client certificates:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/478/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings/

Also, I noticed in your configuration that "anonymous" is set to true.  I know from experience that anonymous will override windows authentication so I wonder if it will also override the need for clients to provide ssl certs.

Comment: that's exactly what the "iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication " section is supposed to do : map the certificate to a user.

Comment: but without anonymous set to true, the web app can't even start, it throws an exception : Security settings for this service require ‘Anonymous’ Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."

Comment: Have you been able to access the website with a client cert that's not from the list of trusted CA's? I'm half suspecting that you're just authenticating as anonymous user. Also, that exception you get when you disable anonymous authentication flags to me that your iis config and your actual application's .config file are not in sync. Anonymous should be disabled for both of them. Finally, I did not not look at your setting for WindowsAuthentication before, but I am almost certain that you can only choose one form of authentication (either windows or client cert), you can't use both.

Comment: No, I haven't been able to access the website with a client cert that's not from the list of trusted CA's.